# How to quickly implement the color change of Appkit?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nscolor

I am realizing the theme of my own application. I hope I can be quickly reacted to by other controls after I modify the color through code.

It's like this.

[image]

But I found that I couldn't change the original system color of NSColor, and I didn't want to change every child control once.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: It's readonly. /*! A dynamic color that reflects the user's current preferred accent color. This color automatically updates when the accent color preference changes. Do not make assumptions about the color space of this color, which may change across releases. */
@property (class, strong, readonly) NSColor *controlAccentColor

Comment: @MarekH Your suggestion is that I should assign every control once? Is the traversal control assigned again when the color changes?

Comment: Your option to try is method swizzling (subclass NSColor won't help). This is advanced topic. Second option is custom drawing of your elements. But havent tested this. Don't fight the framework. I don't think user would like to see different colors than system wide colors